# Show one row of data, click next, hide original row and show next row... and so on

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm using the http://www.advancedcustomfields.com plugin to create custom fields in Wordpress. I'm specifically using the repeater field functionality.

On a page I have a repeater that has an unlimited amount of rows. The usual way of echoing out all the data is the following:

```
<?php $counter = 1; if(get_field('step_by_step_training')): ?>
<?php while(the_repeater_field('step_by_step_training')): ?>
    <p class="training-<?php echo $counter; ?>"><?php the_sub_field('introduction'); ?></p>
<?php $counter++; endwhile; ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is it possible to show one row of data at a time with a next button that when pressed will show the next row of data? I only want one row of data showing at a time so if row 1 is originally showing, when next is clicked it hides row 1 and shows row 2. **Essentially creating a step by step process.**

Eventually I'd like to include a form so the user can submit data.

---

UPDATE:

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php $counter = 1; if(get_field('step_by_step_training')): ?>
<?php while(the_repeater_field('step_by_step_training')): ?>    
    <div class="form-row">
        <p class="training"><?php echo the_sub_field('introduction'); ?></p>
        <button class="next">Next Form Element</button>
    </div>
<?php $counter++; endwhile; ?> 
<?php endif; ?>     
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {    

    // hide all form-rows, but not the first one
    $('.form-row').not(':first').hide();

    $('button.next').click(function(e) {
        // prevent the next buttons from submitting the form
        e.preventDefault();
        // hide this form-row, and show the next one
        $(this).parent('div.form-row').hide().next('div.form-row').show();
    });    

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Unless you can get the fields by ID, and the ID's are sequential, there'd be no way to do this. Yo should create a custom function to handle AJAX requests, and perform pagination.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I've added a counter if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something simple like this using jQuery (I think this is what you wanted?):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  // prepend a 'previous' button to all form-rows except the first
  $('<button>').addClass('previous').text('Previous').prependTo($('.form-row').not(':first'));

  // hide all form-rows, but not the first one
  $('.form-row').not(':first').hide();

  // add the submit button to the last form-row
  $('<input>').prop('type', 'submit').val('Submit Form').appendTo($('.form-row:last'));


  // handle the previous button, we need to use 'on' here as the
  // previous buttons don't exist in the dom at page load
  $('.form-row').on('click', 'button.previous', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div.form-row').hide().prev('div.form-row').show();
  });

$('button.next').click(function(e) {
    // prevent the next buttons from submitting the form
    e.preventDefault();
    // hide this form-row, and show the next one
    $(this).parent('div.form-row').hide().next('div.form-row').show();
});
```

});

some example markup:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">

    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="forename">Forename</label>
        <input type="text" name="forename" />
        <button class="next">Next Form Element</button>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="forename">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" name="surname" />
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <label for="another">Another</label>
        <input type="text" name="another" />
        <button class="next">Next Form Element</button>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="last">Last Form Element</label>
        <input type="text" name="last" />
    </div>

</form>
```

You can add as many form elements to each `form-row` as you want, [here's a fiddle to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/deifwud/aDtFY/4/)

**edit**

Things to note here are that the `previous` buttons are injected to the DOM dynamically, and so is the forms `submit` button (notice how I've removed it from the last `form-row` in the markup)

[Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deifwud/aDtFY/5/)

Comment: Is there a way to submit data via a form with this? Also only want to show one next button at a time. (p.s forgot I asked this!!).

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do - the code above will display one `p` at a time with one `next` button, when clicked it'll show the next one, is this not what you wanted?

Comment: I'd like to include some inputs so they fill in data, I guess it will be all one form, just only showing certain elements at a time? I could then put a final submit button on the last element. How can I show one next button at a time?

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. Nearly there, I've updated my question with what I've got so far. Is there a way to say if it's the last element then change the next button to a submit? Also a back button on steps 2 onwards? (I can ask this in separate questions if thats easier?). Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks very much, I should be able to work this into my foreach loop now.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with a [jQuery accordion menu](http://www.stemkoski.com/stupid-simple-jquery-accordion-menu/).  Some CSS will allow you to minimize the real estate occupied by the deselected rows.  If you want to actually discard and retrieve certain rows based on some identifiable characteristic (for instance, ID number), you'll need to go with AJAX.

Comment: I want them completely hidden so an accordian wouldn't really do it. I've added a counter to the p tag if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own custom method with something like JQuery.

Assign a class to each row, and keep track of which one is selected, when viewing another row simply [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) the one that was showing and [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) the one you wish to display.

If you want to keep your HTML cleaner, you could use the JQuery [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) functionality to assign identifiers to each element and refer to them that way as well.

Most of this all depends on your constraints with wordpress, how it looks & your actual HTML layout

Answer (score 0):

After it's all written to the screen, can't you just hide everything but the first row?  And then each time you click the button, have it hide everything and show the next row.  Try using jquery's next() function.  [jquery - next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

Ah, looks like deifwud beat me to it with a better explanation.